# FindWindowEx in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, findwindowex

I have a query, how can I kill a process with just the class name using FindWindowEx

[image]

Comment: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowThreadProcessId.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have been able to reliably get a window handle back from calling `FindWindowEx` you can then use `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to find the ID of the process from the window handle.

Once you have the process ID you can find the `Process` by that ID and call `Kill()` on it. For example:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Diagnostics

Module Module1

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Function GetWindowThreadProcessId(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr,
                          ByRef lpdwProcessId As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Private Function FindWindowEx(ByVal parentHandle As IntPtr,
                      ByVal childAfter As IntPtr,
                      ByVal lclassName As String,
                      ByVal windowTitle As String) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Sub Main()

        Dim hWnd As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "Chrome_WidgetWin_0", "Spotify Premium")
        Dim ProcessId As Integer
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, ProcessId)

        If ProcessId <> 0 Then
            Dim Process As Process = Process.GetProcessById(ProcessId)
            Process.Kill()
        End If


    End Sub

End Module
```

The tricky part will be making sure that you can always get a window handle. Think about cases when there are multiple instances of the handle. You mention class name but it will likely also be necessary to supply the window title to `FindWindowEx`.

You may also need to consider what happens if calling `Process.Kill()` should throw an exception, for example, if the user that your program is running under doesn't have the rights to kill that particular process.